# Importing CSV data with Coordinates in one column

Tags: qgis, csv

I'm trying to import the Lat/Long coordinates from the "Location" field of a CSV from here :https://data.colorado.gov/Water/DWR-Water-Right-Net-Amounts/acsg-f33s

Unfortunately the coordinates are in a single column and I can't seem to get QGIS to recognize them.

There is a set of columns with UTM, but I think most of my other data is in Lat/Long and I am using Natural Earth basemaps and I'm not sure how to convert the entire world data set to Colorado UTM coordinates.

My goal is to be able to load the CSV data into QGIS and place them accurately over a basemap.

Comment: It's *not* possible to convert the world to one UTM zone, but it's certainly possible to convert UTM to geographic.  It should also be possible to parse any geographic data coordinate (the last column is lat,lon DD), but the primary description uses Public Land Survey (PLS) designations, which are polygon values, if parsed correctly.  Please **edit** your question to choose between ArcGIS and QGIS, and between PLS polygons, UTM points, and geographic points and your preferred response.  Please also take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for guidelines on question formulation

Comment: If you create new columns in your excel sheet and use =LEFT(AI2,10) for lat and =RIGHT(AI2,11) for LNG (then again to remove the brackets) you separate your values that can be load into QGIS

Comment: Your question still focuses on lat/lon parsing, so the final sentence is a sudden turn. Have you researched PLS data conversion?  You're going to need ancillary data to convert township,range,section,quad,quarter-quad,q-q-quad to a polygon.

Comment: There are 2 Questions here please make 2 separate questions one for the csv to QGIS conversion (this question) and one for the PLS Polygon creation

Comment: I edited the question to address only getting the point data into Q. I don't need the Polygons until a later project. Ultimately, the excel code was helpful in allowing me to import the values and have them display accurately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string in the Location field into two separate fields to be able to map the points. First, get rid of the special degree character and then evaluate the tuple string:

```
loc = '(40.37856, -104.756463)'
lat,lon = eval(loc)

>>> lat
40.37856
>>> lon
-104.756463
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the revised question about generating polygons based on PLS quad data.

Comment: The polygon geometries can't be extracted from the dataset. So I think this answers the main part of the question. The polygons should be moved to a new question. You may however label the points with the PLS number if that is what you want.

Comment: The polygon *can* be extracted from the PLS descriptor, with ancillary information (this was why the [US Public Land Survey System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Land_Survey_System) was developed).